# C-space doesn't work in Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I open a C++ file and press C-space to try to select some codes, but it doesn't work now. And there's an error message at the bottom: `symbol's function definition is void semantic-mrub-update`. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I assume that your goal is to enable `set-mark-command` using `C-space`.  The function that is linked to your `C-space` is traceable to `. . . lisp/cedet/semantic/mru-bookmark.el` in the source code of a recent version of Emacs Trunk.  If you search your configuration files and third-party installed libraries / packages, can you find a reference to a key definition that is linked to `C-space` and `semantic-mrub-update` or `semantic-mrub-push`?  That key definition would be a likely suspect . . .

Comment: I had this problem with Emacs (in the terminal) on Lubuntu (14.04.2), solved it by following the instructions in [“ctrl+space” has been bound to invoke some input method and does not work in Emacs or Eclipse auto-complete](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema).

Comment: Possible issue on macOS: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21285/set-mark-command-c-spc-not-recognised-broken

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a conflict with a shortcut defined within your desktop manager. The shortcut C-space is often mapped to switching keyboard input methods. You might want to change (or remove) that shortcut in the keyboard input method preferences. I had the same problem after switching to Ubuntu 14.04 and solved it this way.